# Add view programmatically to RelativeLayout android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

how can I do to add child view programmatically to RelativeLayout at a given position?

For example, to reflect the following picture:

[image]

my xml: (com.example.TransparentSlidingDrawer child is a simple class that extends with LinearLayout)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
 <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        >
<com.example.TransparentSlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/popup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
     <RelativeLayout 
         android:id="@+id/relativelayout_imageview_textviews_slider"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         >    
     </RelativeLayout>


</com.example.TransparentSlidingDrawer>

</ScrollView> 
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/open_close_slider"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    />
```

---

this is my function that this function does not work well :

```
private void addChild(){
    RelativeLayout relativelayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_imageview_textviews_slider);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    imageparams.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    textparams.setMargins(0, 25, 5, 0);

    imageparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    imageparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; ++i){
        ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
        btn.setId(i+1);
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        txt.setText("text"+i);
        txt.setId(i+1);
        textparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, btn.getId());
        textparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, btn.getId());
        relativelayout.addView(btn, imageparams);
        relativelayout.addView(txt, textparams);
    }

}
```

Comment: what is a RelativeLayout inside your custom LinearLayout for?

Comment: for adding textviews and imageviews programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aligning the textviews with button tops and lefts here:

```
    textparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, btn.getId());
    textparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, btn.getId());
```

You need to do the same for the ImageButtons - except align the first one with the parent, then each subsequent one you need to align the top to the previous ImageButton (here is fake code):

```
    btn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, btnAbove.getId());
```

Then keep a reference to the previous button in "btnAbove" at the end of your loop like:

btnAbove = btn;

Comment: ok,now,Where is my problem? http://paste.ubuntu.com/6824994/   http://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Ckw.jpg

Comment: you are telling the textviews to fill the parent.. they should probably WRAP_CONTENT not your code here -> RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT (problem), RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT (problem));

Comment: I changed it to warp_content but I have the same problem earlier.(http://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Ckw.jpg)

Comment: what is the problem? Also, you may need to create new params with each object - you keep adding rules to the same ones

Answer (score 0):

Each view in the layout requires its own `LayoutParams` object. Reusing the same object won't work the way you want.

Also, prefer using an activity context for UI widgets to get your app theme properly applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
final TextView titleView = (TextView) itemLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.titleView);
```

Rather than creating all those additional parameters this will take care of the position in the layout